# Installing a submodule of date-fns using npm

Tags: node.js, function, npm, npm-install, date-fns

Let say I have the following line in my util.js

```
const subMonths = require('date-fns/subMonths')
```

How can I install just the submodule, e.g. date-fns/sub-months, using npm? I don't want to install the whole date-fns package itself as it's just too big taking up 5+ MB.

Thanks.